# socket hang up in node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, request, socket.io

I am using node 0.6.10 version and I got the error today while uploading a file to amazon S3.
I am using knox(@0.0.9) module with request(@2.9.153).

```
[2012-03-06 22:33:34.251] [ERROR] xyxyxyxy- Error uploading to S3: Error: soc
ket hang up
    at createHangUpError (http.js:1104:15)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (http.js:1207:27)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at Array.0 (net.js:320:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Also, I checked that I have http.js in the following modules and none of them have setTimeout (did a grep).

```
./express/lib/http.js
./express/node_modules/connect/lib/http.js
./socket.io/lib/transports/http.js
```

I found that there are couple of posts on the same issue, and looks like the issue was fixed in some older version. Am I using any older version ?
Here is my complete node_modules:

```
├── async@0.1.8
├─┬ express@2.5.8
│ ├─┬ connect@1.8.5
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.9
│ │ └── qs@0.4.2
│ ├── mime@1.2.4
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.0
│ └── qs@0.4.2
├─┬ glossary@0.1.1
│ ├─┬ natural@0.0.69
│ │ ├── apparatus@0.0.6
│ │ ├── sylvester@0.0.21
│ │ └── underscore@1.3.1
│ ├── pos@0.1.1
│ └── underscore@1.1.7
├─┬ jade@0.20.0
│ ├── commander@0.2.1
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.0
├── knox@0.0.9
├── log4js@0.4.1
├─┬ mongoose@2.5.9
│ ├── hooks@0.1.9
│ └── mongodb@0.9.7-3-5
├─┬ nodemailer@0.3.6
│ ├─┬ mailcomposer@0.1.7
│ │ └── mimelib-noiconv@0.1.6
│ └─┬ simplesmtp@0.1.13
│   └── rai@0.1.6
├── redis@0.7.1
├── request@2.9.153
├─┬ socket.io@0.9.0
│ ├── policyfile@0.0.4
│ ├── redis@0.6.7
│ └─┬ socket.io-client@0.9.0
│   ├── uglify-js@1.2.5
│   ├─┬ ws@0.4.0
│   │ ├── commander@0.5.0
│   │ └── options@0.0.2
│   └── xmlhttprequest@1.2.2
└── yql@0.4.6
```

Comment: Try nuking your `node_modules` directory and running `npm install` again.

Comment: found the problem. it was happening due to the issue mentioned in https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/56. Windows path problem was incorrect and that's why it was throwing 403 internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the thread, with the answer,

found the problem. it was happening due to the issue mentioned in [github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/56](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/56). Windows path problem was incorrect and that's why it was throwing 403 internally.